# Ansible: answer to prompt from a package installation

Tags: ansible, expect

I'm trying to install `jitsi-meet` package with Ansible.

When you install jitsi-meet, there is a prompt with a message: `SSL certificate for the Jitsi Meet instance` and the user has to choose between `Generate a new self-signed ...` or `I want to use my own certificate`.

Then, there is a second text: `Full local server path to the SSL key file` and a text area already pre-filled with `/etc/ssl/example.org.key` in which I would like to add something like `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem`

Then, there is a second text: `Full local server path to the SSL certificate file` and a text area already pre-filled with `/etc/ssl/example.org.crt` in which I would like to add something like `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/cert.pem`

I'm using ansible to do so. I've read that I could use the "expect" module, but I'm not sure if that is the right way and how to write this. Here is what I did, but it doesn't work:

```
- name: Install Jitsi-meet
  expect:
    command: apt install -y jitsi-meet
    responses:
        "SSL certificate for the Jitsi Meet instance": "I want to use my own certificate"
        "Full local server path to the SSL key file": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem"
        "Full local server path to the SSL certificate file": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/cert.pem"
```

Comment: hello @meaz check this link https://github.com/udima-university/ansible-jitsi-meet you have a well structred playbook to which you can compare your own or use it all the way

Comment: the problem is that 1. it is not recommended from the official guidelines to install manually [handbook](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-manual) and 2. I would still need to know how to handle this situation, even if the package I would like to install is something else.

Comment: "but it doesn't work" ... because it rebooted your computer? drank your coffee? installed a bitcoin miner instead? Furthermore, are you aware of the [`debconf` subsystem](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/debconf.7.html) of which I would guess you'll want to pay special attention to `env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline` in order to stop it from using `dialog` as the default, which `expect` almost certainly will not interact with

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel indeed debconf subsystem with `env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline` seems to do the trick.